elements of a method claim that are not "acted" on by the method
claim 1:
A computer implemented method, comprising:
a) receiving a first item description from a first user's device;
b) novel step; and
c) transmitting items corresponding to the first item description to the first user's device.

The act of Step (c) is "transmitting".
The phrase "items corresponding to the first item description" implies that these items are introduced in step (c).
Questions:

Since the act of step (c) is transmitting, does it matter how "items corresponding to the first item description" come into existence or are identified?
In other words, assuming step (b) is where the novelty of the claim lies, and that step (b) does not involve the "items corresponding to the first item description", does it matter how "items corresponding to the first item description" come into existence or are identified?


I would try to minimize claim language that is not supported by algorithm/flowchart/stepwise in the specification. If you have an algorithm, the algorithm will specify how the items came into existence (and it will limit the claim). If you're just trying to functionally claim some outcome irrespective of how it is accomplished you will not get far nowadays.
